# Transacciones MySQL ( PHP )

Tags: php, mysql, transacciones

Necesito hacer 2 inserciones, una en **tablaX** y la otra en **tablaY**, esto medio transacciones, ya que si alguna de las 2 inserciones falla se debe de cancelar la operación.

Pero, ¿cómo puedo obtener el Id recién insertado en la **tablaX** para luego insertarlo en la **tablaY**?

Verán, tengo algo como lo siguiente:

```
$conex = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);

//Se inicia la transacción
$conex->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO tablaX(valor) VALUES("valor1")";
$conex->query($sql);

$idTablaX = $conex->insert_id;

if($idTablaX){
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO tablaY(idx,valor) VALUES($idTablaX,"valor1")";
    $conex->query($sql2);

    $conex->commit();
}
```

Sin embargo, *$idTablaX* siempre devuelve 0,
y por lo tanto la segunda inserción, en **tablaY**, no sucede.

Les agradezco su apoyo, saludos!

Comment: te aconsejaría que ejecutaras un echo $sql2, para saber que te esta devolviendo el query.

Comment: y si haces depues del insert un Select LAST_INSERT_ID() para obtener ese id insertado y cargas $idTablaX

Comment: Hola @Manny 
En teoría $conex->insert_id es lo que está realizando, sólo que me obtiene un '0'

Comment: ok, entonces estas seguro que el insert a la TablaX se esta realizando en la db? tu ID es autoincrementable?

Comment: Perdon, el commit() lo realizo dentro del if, por lo tanto este no se aplica, en seguida corrijo el código

Comment: prueba poniendo $idTablaX = $conex->mysql_insert_id();